# copy a folder with the date of the next day

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a script to copy a file that is created every day with the date of the next useful day.

Example

today he creates with the date of tomorrow, 
2017-12-21

Sometimes he can create with two, three days 
2017-12-23
or 
2017-12-24

```
$source = "C:\folder\yyy-mm-dd"
$item = "OpenPos_yyymmdd.txt"
$dest = "e:\tmp\"

$vl = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select Name -First 1 


for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays( + $i))
 $d2 = $d.ToString("yyy-mm-dd")

 if ($d2 -eq $vl )
 {

 }

}
```

Comment: _"Try to find 7 times find the file with the date of the next useful day"_. What do you mean? That's not clear.

Comment: try 7 times until you find a file with the date of the next day
 I can move forward a bit more in the script

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have to reword that statement so that it becomes clear what you want help with.

Comment: Okay, I reformulated

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen can you help me

Comment: Its still a bit confusing... so u want to find a file that has a file for everyday and copy only the file that is dated for tomorrow?

Comment: @ShanayL I want my script to search for a specific file that will be named with the date of the next day.

Ex: today is 12/20/2017, the server is going to create a file with date name tomorrow 12/21/2017.
I want my script to copy this file 12/21/2017.

It can happen that the server builds with the date later
ex: 12/22, 12/23
So I need my script to loop until I find a file with the date on

Comment: ok so the date you are referring to is the creation date of the source file? once you find it name it `file_tomorrow`

Comment: @ShanayL Yes.
Ex:
The server will create a file for the next day
example20171221.txt

Comment: so the script is not creating the file `example20171221.txt`. The server is? Are you just copying the file the server created?

Comment: @ShanayL   no. is the server that creates

Comment: I'm sorry i wont be able to help. I am confused. Your script and what you are saying is not matching. Maybe you need to reword your question.

Comment: @ShanayL 

Sorry,
I did not see your whole question 

The server is? Are you just copying the file the server created? 
Yes, the server that creates it.
I'm just copying.

Comment: ok. is there a reason you are trying to loop through 7 days?u want to copy 7 days into separate folders?

Comment: @ShanayL The reason for a loop is because the server might anticipate two days or more ahead.

Ex: It can create a file with the date 20171225 or 26, or 27....

Answer (score 0):

If all u need to do is copy the file you will need creation date by going through each file instead of just choosing the first one. So I encorporated a `foreach loop` to go through each file the server created.

You can use `-recurse` to go through folders if need be.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

```
$source = "C:\folder\yyy-mm-dd"
$dest = "e:\tmp\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source | %{

    $creationdate = ([datetime]$_.CreationTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++)
    {
        $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        if ($d -eq $creationdate )
        {
            Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination $dest
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to filter the file 
et-ChildItem -Path $source | %{

    $creationdate = ([datetime]$_.CreationTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

The file that I need to filter is this one

 BmfTF_OpenPos_2017-12-22.TXT
I need to pick up only filter 2017-12-22.txt

Comment: @ShabayL
Sorry, Is date in the filename.

Comment: You said you need to go through a folder and read files. Are you trying to do one file only? Are all of the file formats the same. Please edit your question with explaining that you are only trying to copy files from a folder that a server creates, so that future people can understand what you are asking.

Comment: I just need to copy file that is created with the date in the filename ex: OpenPos_2017-12-22.TXT.
No copying by date modified.
Yes, Copy based on file name.

Comment: i want to help but I no longer know what you are asking. If you want to get the date out of the file name use the `Split` function.... the best of luck to you.